# Display reCAPTCHA in a windows application form

Tags: c#, winforms, recaptcha

As part of my application, I have to display the google reCAPTCHA for the user. Unforchunetly I don't familiar with web stuff, specially reCAPTCHA.
I use the below code

```
string nitroUser = @"myUserName";
string nitroPass = @"MyPass";
string apiURL = $"https://nitroflare.com/api/v2/getDownloadLink?user={nitroUser}&premiumKey={nitroPass}&file={nitroflareCode}";
using (WebClient getNitroflareLink = new WebClient())
{
    getNitroflareLink.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
    string json = getNitroflareLink.DownloadString(apiURL);
    dynamic json_data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
    if (json_data.result.recaptchaPublic != null)
    {
        {
            string sitekey = json_data.result.recaptchaPublic; // return 6Lenx_USAAAAAF5L1pmTWvWcH73dipAEzNnmNLgy

            // Load webBrowser 
            string html = $"<html><head><title>reCAPTCHA demo: Simple page</title><script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js' async defer></script></head><body><form action='?' method='POST'><div class='g-recaptcha' data-sitekey='{sitekey}'></div><br/><input type='submit' value='Submit'></form></body></html>";

            webBrowser1.DocumentText = html;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the documentation

> In any request you might get the following response, and when you do - you should display to the user a Google's ReCAPTCHA v2 using the public key you have received in the response:

```
{
  "type": "success",
  "result": {
    "recaptchaPublic": "6Lenx_USAAAAAF5L1pmTWvWcH73dipAEzNnmNLgy"
  }
}
```

> After the user completed the challenge, you should send the same request again with another GET parameter

Comment: So what does or doesn't this code do?

Comment: @CodeCaster It should return a direct link from some link like this [link](http://nitroflare.com/view/5400A5A81C36000/22125468-handy-transitions-for-premiere-pro-ShareAE.com.zip).
some time, the user should solve the reCAPTCHA ,before he get a direct link.